# Need help reading and updating json file with PHP

Tags: php, arrays, json, updating, editing

I have about 3000 json files in a folder that I need to edit. I have done some research but everything I have found does not seem to work for my situation. I believe it's because when extracting the data to an array the the data from attributes is in a sub array.

I need to open each file and edit the `"trait_type"` name. I need to remove Vehicle/ for each trait type.

For example I need to edit

`"trait_type": "Vehicle/Exterior"`

and change to this.

`"trait_type": "Exterior"`

Any help would be much appreciated.

JSON file

```
{
    "name":"2020 Mercedes-Benz Sl550 ",
    "description":"Fully Loaded",
    "image":"http://www.websitename.com/images/2020_mercedes-benz_1.jpg",
    "price":"69900",
    "miles":4500,
    "date":1647530418343,
    "attributes":[
        {
            "trait_type":"Vehicle/Exterior",
            "value":"Black"
        },
        {
            "trait_type":"Vehicle/Interior",
            "value":"Black"
        },
        {
            "trait_type":"Vehicle/Engine",
            "value":"4.7L V8 32V"
        },
        {
            "trait_type":"Vehicle/Fuel",
            "value":"GAS"
        }
    ],
    "Stock Number":"43212"
}
```

Comment: Can `trait_type` be anything other than `Vehicle/Exterior`? If yes, do you want to only change those?

Comment: *"I have about 3000 json files in a folder that I need to edit."* ... PHP can be run from the console, you need not do this in the browser for "utility" scripts. The advantage of console executions is you need not worry with browser-side timings. All just runs smoothly. E.g. `php somescript.php`

Comment: @GetSet - Where did they say that they are doing this, or want to do this, through a browser?

Comment: They didnt @M.Eriksson but they did say `3000 json files` which sounds like a "pre-parsing" job hence on "that I need to edit".

Comment: @GetSet - It could just as easily be a utility script they want to run through the console. Either way, we don't know how they want to execute it, nor is that the question they have. Just thinking of not distracting the OP from answering the questions needed to give them a proper answer.

Comment: I wouldnt necessarily look at as a distraction. I do it all the time being that i like PHP. And their file handling library of methods. So I offered my advice as *any* commenter can do. Whether OP with zero code, zero intentions shown can benefit, we shall see.

Comment: Yet correct answer below (@davidkonrad) handles my questions. Dont know why @M.Eriksson objected. OP specifically states in question "I have about 3000 json files in a folder that I need to edit.". Where is the confusion that this is non-browser? If it were browser, why edit it once?

Comment: @GetSet - I honestly have no idea what you're referring to now. The below answer would work in both the console or the browser. the fact that they have 3000 files doesn't clarify anything about how they execute the script. Ofc we can suggest improvements to the posters scripts, but my point is that we should avoid writing comments suggesting improvements we don't even know actually are relevant. Doing that risks cluttering the comment sections, making the OP miss relevant questions about their actual issue. That's unfortunately a quite common phenomena here on SO.

Comment: The script is adding a back slash to the forward slash in the URL in the image field.

Answer (score 2):

- Use `glob` to fetch all JSON filenames
- For each file, read the content and convert it to `stdClass`
- Cycle through `attributes`, do a simple `str_replace` on any occurrence of `trait_type`
- Convert the `stdClass` back to JSON string
- Overwrite each file with the newly replaced content

---

```
$files = glob('*.json');
foreach ($files as $file) {
  $json = json_decode(file_get_contents($file));
  foreach($json->attributes as $attrib) {
    if (isset($attrib->trait_type)) {
      $attrib->trait_type = str_replace('Vehicle/', '', $attrib->trait_type);
    }
  }
  file_put_contents($file, json_encode($json, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT));  
}
```

You should skip `JSON_PRETTY_PRINT`, just using it for demonstration purposes, so it is easier to see that `Vehicle/` is actually removed. Obvious PHP should have write-access to the directory.

Comment: That worked perfectly. Thank you so much!!!!! I was able to edit other information but I was having so much trouble getting to the trait type.

Answer (score 1):

Ohh, didn't make in time :D

```
<?php

if(!is_dir('fixed')){
    mkdir('fixed');
}

foreach(glob('*.json') as $json_file){
    
    $data = json_decode(file_get_contents($json_file));

    foreach($data->attributes as $key => $attribute){

        $data->attributes[$key]->trait_type = preg_replace('/^vehicle\//i', '', $attribute->trait_type);

    }

    file_put_contents('fixed/'.$json_file, json_encode($data, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT));

}
```

Comment: This will create a folder to store the new edited files to make sure everything is ok before replacing the files.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [array_walk_recursive](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-walk-recursive.php), it will update the array and you can encode it again to JSON (use [JSON constants](https://www.php.net/manual/fr/json.constants.php) to configure the [json_encode](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php) behavior) :

```php
<?php
// better use a named function if you do it very often
function my_modifier (&$v, $k){
    if ($k == 'trait_type') 
        $v = 'XYZ';
}

$data = '{"name":"2020 Mercedes-Benz Sl550 ","description":"Fully Loaded","image":"http:\/\/www.websitename.com\/images\/2020_mercedes-benz_1.jpg","price":"69900","miles":4500,"date":1647530418343,"attributes":[{"trait_type":"Vehicle\/Exterior","value":"Black"},{"trait_type":"Vehicle\/Interior","value":"Black"},{"trait_type":"Vehicle\/Engine","value":"4.7L V8 32V"},{"trait_type":"Vehicle\/Fuel","value":"GAS"}],"Stock Number":"43212"}';

$arr = json_decode($data, true);
array_walk_recursive($arr, 'my_modifier');
$data = json_encode($arr, JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES|JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
// done, $data is upadted.
echo "<pre>$data";
```

Comment: I just noticed an issue I did not notice before. For some reason after the script is run it changes the image field from "image":"http://www.websitename.com/images/2020_mercedes-benz_1.jpg", to "image":"http:\/\/www.websitename.com\/images\/2020_mercedes-benz_1.jpg",

Comment: It's adding a back slash to the forward-slash in the URL in the image field.